# Flutter theming

Tags: flutter, themes

I have created a them from a color scheme and an a text theme. Here is my theme file.

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intellaview_mobile/constants/constants.dart';

extension AppTextStyleVariants on TextStyle {
  TextStyle get italic => copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
  TextStyle get regular => copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal);
  TextStyle get semiBold => copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);
  TextStyle get bold => copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  TextStyle colorize(Color color) => copyWith(color: color);
}

extension NamedTextStylesFromTextTheme on TextTheme {
  TextStyle get listItem1 => headline4!;
  TextStyle get listItem2 => headline5!;
  TextStyle get button1 => button!;
  TextStyle get button2 => headline6!;
}

class AppTheme {
  static final TextTheme _appTextTheme = TextTheme(
    headline1: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    headline2: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    headline3: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 14.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    // listItem1
    headline4: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      // semiBold
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      fontSize: 16.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    // listItem2
    headline5: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 14.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    // button2
    headline6: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 12.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    subtitle1: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      // semiBold
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 16.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    subtitle2: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      // semiBold
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 12.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    bodyText1: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 12.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    bodyText2: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      fontSize: 12.0,
      color: AppColors.primary,
    ),
    button: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 14.0,
      color: AppColors.primary.shade500,
    ),
    overline: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      // semiBold
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 10.0,
      color: AppColors.primary.shade500,
    ),
    caption: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 8.0,
      color: AppColors.primary.shade300,
    ),
  );

  static final TextTheme _onPrimaryTextTheme = _appTextTheme.apply(
    bodyColor: AppColors.onPrimary,
    displayColor: AppColors.onPrimary,
  );

  static final ColorScheme _appColorScheme = ColorScheme(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primary: AppColors.primary.shade800,
    primaryVariant: AppColors.primary.shade500,
    secondary: AppColors.secondary.shade500,
    secondaryVariant: AppColors.secondary.shade800,
    background: Colors.white,
    surface: Colors.white,
    error: AppColors.error,
    onPrimary: Colors.white,
    onSecondary: AppColors.primary.shade800,
    onBackground: AppColors.primary.shade800,
    onSurface: AppColors.primary.shade800,
    onError: Colors.white,
  );

  static ThemeData? finalAppTheme;

  static DividerThemeData _dividerThemeData(ThemeData themeData) {
    return themeData.dividerTheme.copyWith(space: 1, thickness: 1);
  }

  static final AppBarTheme _appBarTheme = AppBarTheme(
    color: AppColors.primary,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColors.onPrimary),
    actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColors.onPrimary),
    textTheme: _onPrimaryTextTheme,
    titleTextStyle: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    elevation: 4,
  );

  static ThemeData get app {
    if (null == finalAppTheme) {
      ThemeData themeData = ThemeData.from(
        colorScheme: _appColorScheme,
        textTheme: _appTextTheme,
      );

      finalAppTheme = themeData.copyWith(
        buttonColor: themeData.colorScheme.secondary,
        // selectedRowColor: AppColors.selectedRowColor,
        appBarTheme: _appBarTheme,
        dividerTheme: _dividerThemeData(themeData),
        canvasColor: AppColors.primary,
        disabledColor: AppColors.primary.shade100,
      );
    }
    return finalAppTheme!;
  }
}
```

I create my material app with that theme.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: Strings.lang.kIntellaViewMobile,
      theme: AppTheme.app,
      initialRoute: LoginScreen.route,
      routes: {
        AddEditSwitch.route: (context) => AddEditSwitch(),
        AlertsScreen.route: (context) => AlertsScreen(),
        BladesScreen.route: (context) => BladesScreen(),
        ConnectionsScreen.route: (context) => ConnectionsScreen(),
        DashboardScreen.route: (context) => DashboardScreen(),
        SwitchesScreen.route: (context) => SwitchesScreen(),
        EnableBluetoothScreen.route: (context) => EnableBluetoothScreen(),
        FactoryResetScreen.route: (context) => FactoryResetScreen(),
        HealthCheckScreen.route: (context) => HealthCheckScreen(),
        IntellaViewHomePage.route: (context) => IntellaViewHomePage(title: Strings.lang.kIntellaViewMobile),
        LoginScreen.route: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        MaintenanceScreen.route: (context) => MaintenanceScreen(),
        SwitchInfoScreen.route: (context) => SwitchInfoScreen(),
        UsersScreen.route: (context) => UsersScreen(),
      },
      navigatorObservers: [AppState.instance],
    );
  }
}
```

However, I get strange colors and results in places that I don't expect.

For instance. When the child of my Scaffold : Drawer gets rebuilt it comes in with a theme where everything is white. My primary color is gone. My canvas color is gone. Where is flutter getting this seemingly random them from? Is there a guide to tell me where flutter gets its theme information for various widgets from. I know that the Drawer is not using my theme, so where did the drawer theme come from?

Comment: Flutter 2.0.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1d9032c7e1 (13 days ago) • 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
Engine • revision 05e680e202
Tools • Dart 2.12.3

Comment: Hi! Could you provide code of your Drawer?

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out the problem. It turns that I didn't fully understand how ThemeData.from(ColorScheme, TextTheme) works.

Apparently if your ColorScheme uses a brightness of Brightness.light then your primary color will be the primary color that you pass in. If you choose Brightness of Brightness.dark flutter will use the surfaceColor for the primary color. Note the code below from Theme.from(...)

```
    final Color primarySurfaceColor = isDark ? colorScheme.surface : colorScheme.primary;
    final Color onPrimarySurfaceColor = isDark ? colorScheme.onSurface : colorScheme.onPrimary;
```

So I was getting the opposite colors of what I was expecting.

My fix was to change the color scheme to Brightness.light and I got the expected colors.

I haven't seen a good tutorial on constructing more complex light / dark themes. They all seem oversimplified compared to the app I'm working on. If you know on then please post it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since some default widgets used color from ThemeData directly, set colors in the ColorScheme may not enough.

Example in some default widgets:

```dart
// this may be used
Theme.of(context).backgroundColor

// instead of this
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background.
```

You can do sth like this:

```dart
ColorScheme scheme = isDarkMode ? ThemeConstant.darkScheme : ThemeConstant.lightScheme;

return ThemeData(
  primaryColor: scheme.primary,
  backgroundColor: scheme.background,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: scheme.background,
  colorScheme: scheme,
  ...
);
```